# Communication issues between Arch Linux and iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, bluez, bluetooth-lowenergy, archlinux-arm

I'm running Arch Linux and the Bluez libraries on my computer, and I'm trying to connect to an iPad [w/ Retina] over BLE. I can see the iPad in bluetoothctl, pair it, trust it, and connect to it. My question is in two parts:

1) I want to be able to select the attributes, more specifically for the MAP service. However, running

```
list-attributes
```

either during or outside of the connection returns no information.

2) My iPad cannot see the computer like it can see the iPad, either through the Settings --> Bluetooth menu or the CBCentralManager in an app that I'm developing. My computer is set to be discoverable and pairable forever, but it just doesn't find it.

How would I be able to connect to the iPad appropriately, if there even is a way?

Comment: I don't know a lot about IOS. But I do know that [MAP](https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/MAP.aspx) is not a GATT based profile. As such, it does not have attributes.

Comment: "My computer is set to be discoverable". You may want to explain how you attempted to do that. In case you did it incorrectly. For example, `bluetoothctl` (if I recall correctly) does not have a way to make the device discoverable  forever and the setting only lasts as long as `bluetoothctl` is running.

Comment: Another way I've been trying it is with `hciconfig hci0 leadv`. Once I do that, the iPad finally sees the computer. What it doesn't see, though, is any services on the computer. I went back and checked the computer with `hciconfig -a hci0` and am getting "Unspecified" next to Service Classes. As for bluetoothctl, there are settings for turning on discoverable and pairable forever in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf`.

Comment: @Zimano Your answer worked for me. I was able to establish a btgatt-server instance and my iPad not only caught it, it also found services. If you put your comment as an answer, I'll choose it as the best one. Thanks!

Comment: @WilliamPutnam Removed my comment, check the answer :) I expanded on it as well, providing some other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer to anyone using BlueZ user space tools:

> OP mentioned in the comments that he utilized `hcitool`. It's best not to use `hciconfig` nor `hcitool` as these are in the process of
>   being phased out of BlueZ and have been unmaintained for a very long
>   time. They are prone to errors and the raw calls these programs make are blocking and cause interference with other Bluetooth applications.

BlueZ publishes some methods in order for users to use its Bluetooth (LE) functionality for applications or tasks: DBus and a lower-level approach. Programs included in the BlueZ user space package include `bluetoothctl`, which uses DBus for bluetooth related tasks, such as scanning, advertising and GATT. Tools like `btmgmt`, which can be considered a maintained  version of `hcitool`, use the lower level libraries. BlueZ recommends using the [DBus API](http://www.bluez.org/bluez-5-api-introduction-and-porting-guide/) for applications.  Be sure to have compiled the source code and have followed the [recommended instructions](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/bluez.html) to use the mentioned tools. Also always check the licensing on mentioned tools and source files as some can not be included in proprietary software.

---

### DBus-less solution:

If using `bluetoothctl` or `DBus` doesn't work out for you, I would suggest you use `btmgmt`. It can be found in the `/tools` folder of the [user space source code](http://www.bluez.org/download/).

If you're looking for or wanting to include GATT-related tasks, you can use `btgatt-client` to act as a GATT Client or `btgatt-server` to act as a GATT server from that same `/tools` folder.
These do not use DBus, nor the corresponding Bluetooth Daemon (`bluetoothd`) like `bluetoothctl` does

### DBus solution:

What is most likely the cause of you not seeing services using `bluetoothctl`, however, is that you are not running the aforementioned bluetooth daemon with the `-E` flag (experimental). Currently, all GATT-related functionality is only usable when running in this experimental mode. (They're working to get it out of experimental-only mode) I think because it's still being developed. If I recall correctly BlueZ can also be configured/installed in this experimental mode, so that no manual actions are required.

To restart the BlueZ Daemon (`bluetoothd`) with GATT enabled run:

`sudo service bluetooth stop && bluetoothd -E`

In most cases, when stopping the bluetooth service, your bluetooth controller will power down and `bluetoothctl` won't respond to user input/freezes on startup. If this is indeed the case, use `btmgmt` and issue a `power on` to power the bluetooth controller again.

Answer (score 0):

1. To VIEW the MAP service attributes, use list-attributes to view them. Ensure proper spelling. To SELECT the MAP service, you need to list-attributes then select-attributes, in that order.
2. It sounds like your ipad is having a problem. Perhaps try turning it off and on again. Make sure you have bluetooth enabled!
3. There is always a way!

Comment: 1) As stated in my question, I already tried using list-attributes. Nothing appeared for me to select.

2) Bluetooth is on and enabled. I have tried power cycling it.

Comment: This is not really a complete answer to the OP's questions. Suggest editing or deleting.

Comment: Indeed, "restart ipad, make sure bluetooth is enabled" is almost insulting, haha